# DateTime Python Parsing

Tags: python, datetime

I'm having some trouble with the datetime library. Here is my code:

```
import time
import datetime 
TIME = 2014-10-20 14:31:27
DATETIME = datetime.datetime.strptime(TIME, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

When I try to run this, I get:

```
DATETIME = datetime.datetime.strptime(TIME, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be string, not datetime.datetime
```

Is TIME not a string?

TIME is getting its value from the Tweepy Library but the documentation doesn't say if the time it passes is actually a string or not.

Comment: When *I* try to run that, I get a `SyntaxError` (as expected, because that assignment to `TIME` makes no sense). If I add quotes around it, it works just fine. Given that you apparently already **have** a `datetime`, why try to re-convert it?

Comment: No, as you forgot the quotes. I'm _very_ surprised you actually got a message like that, it should crash much faster... If you get the value from somewhere else, what does `type(TIME)` return?

Comment: This ended up working `DATETIME = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(TIME), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: @OmarAnsari yes, but that works because you *already have a `datetime` object* - why are you converting it **at all**?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
thedate = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

You can check the result with:

```
print thedate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d @ %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
TIME = 2014-10-20 14:31:27
```

is not a valid Python code. I understand that you don't create the object this way but get it from a library, and it's not a string but datetime object. So, the error message is self explanatory. You don't need to parse this object, treating it as a string, to get datetime, it's already a datetime object.

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be string, not datetime.datetime

the exception says that TIME is already `datetime` object. Remove `strptime()` line from your code. `DATETIME = TIME`